# Validation error while deploying a quick action on Case object

Tags: lightning, deployment, metadata, quickaction

I am deploying a quick action on case object using VS Code but I am getting the below validation error and I am not able to remove this error :-

```
Case.Email_Random_Name  Action  0   0   Required fields are missing: [DefaultValueFormula]
```

Please help me how to fix this error.

Below is the metadata for the quick action that I am trying to deploy :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuickAction xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>Random Description</description>
    <fieldOverrides>
        <field>BccIds</field>
    </fieldOverrides>
    <fieldOverrides>
        <field>CcAddress</field>
        <formula>IF(BEGINS(Case.OwnerId,&apos;005&apos;), Case.Owner:User.Email, NULL)</formula>
    </fieldOverrides>
    <fieldOverrides>
        <field>HtmlBody</field>
        <formula>&apos;&apos;</formula>
    </fieldOverrides>
    <fieldOverrides>
        <field>ReplyToEmailMessageId</field>
        <formula>NULL</formula>
    </fieldOverrides>
    <fieldOverrides>
        <field>Subject</field>
        <formula>&apos;re: &apos;+Case.Subject</formula>
    </fieldOverrides>
    <fieldOverrides>
        <field>ToAddress</field>
        <formula>Case.Contact.Email</formula>
    </fieldOverrides>
    <fieldOverrides>
        <field>ValidatedFromAddress</field>
        <literalValue>test@random.com</literalValue>
    </fieldOverrides>
    <optionsCreateFeedItem>true</optionsCreateFeedItem>
    <quickActionLayout>
        <layoutSectionStyle>TwoColumnsLeftToRight</layoutSectionStyle>
        <quickActionLayoutColumns>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>ValidatedFromAddress</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>ToAddress</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>CcAddress</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>BccAddress</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>Subject</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
            <quickActionLayoutItems>
                <emptySpace>false</emptySpace>
                <field>HtmlBody</field>
                <uiBehavior>Edit</uiBehavior>
            </quickActionLayoutItems>
        </quickActionLayoutColumns>
        <quickActionLayoutColumns/>
    </quickActionLayout>
    <quickActionSendEmailOptions>
        <ignoreDefaultEmailTemplateSubject>false</ignoreDefaultEmailTemplateSubject>
    </quickActionSendEmailOptions>
    <standardLabel>SendEmail</standardLabel>
    <targetObject>EmailMessage</targetObject>
    <targetParentField>Parent</targetParentField>
    <type>SendEmail</type>
</QuickAction>
```

Thanks,
SFDC Alex

Comment: Hi there, 

Did you have a look at this post already? 
https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pgdVQAQ

Looks like this might help.

Comment: DefaultValueFormula has formula value, this metadata doesn't have it, so it fails. you need to retrieve it using API version > 43.0 if the quickaction has formula.



https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickaction.htm

------------------------------------------------------------------

FieldOverride

formula: Specifies the formula to use when setting a field’s predefined value. Supported for single-select picklists as of API version 43.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<fieldOverrides>
    <field>BccIds</field>
</fieldOverrides>
```

At this point, there was no formula tag in the metadata hence the error was coming. I manually wrote the formula tag in the metadata file as :-

```
<fieldOverrides>
    <field>BccIds</field>
    <formula>NULL</formula>
</fieldOverrides>
```

I populated the formula field with whatever value I wanted to be deployed in the target org.